# Align parent of floating divs on center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="bigParent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/te9fzaub/4/   - Simple example;

Ok, so i have the code above, what i'm trying to achieve is to have `.child` floated left and `.parent` on `display:inline-block;` but being centered in `.bigParent`.
 The issue i'm getting i that if the 3rd `.child div` isn't fitting in the `.bigParent` width, it puts it on a new line and it makes `.parent div's` width 100%;
Thanks in advance, love this community!

Comment: can u post a fiddle what u have tried..

Comment: I can't because i use a lot of php and javascript, i will try to make a demo tho, give me a minute.

Comment: Please share the fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLawrob1/ ? :) add what you need in there and update it :)

Comment: what is the width of your child element or make fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/te9fzaub/  So i want the red one to have only the width of the 2 green ones and to be aligned on center, is it possible?
Also, the red div has a dynamic width, it isn't fixed.

Comment: 100% of what? The `.bigParent`?

Comment: if you want all the 3 child div's to be in same line then you should increase the width .bigParent {width:366px}

Comment: i do not know the width of the .bigParent that is just an example, if i resize the window, i get in that situation and i want the wrapper to be aligned on center

Comment: Cannot. The wrapper is expanded to its parent's width because it tries to place all children in one line (although fails, and doesn't shrink back). So technically it's already **centered**.

Comment: I know but it's not mandatory to use exactly the html and the css i used, the point is to get those children aligned on center but every time it exceeds the parent width to start a new from left, not the center. As i've showed in my answer but in CSS

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a method, but i'd like to use only css if possible. I've posted it as answer so maybe others having this problem might consider this a temporary solution.

```
var maxWidth = $('.bigParent').width(),
    childWidth = $('.child').width(),
    nrOfChildren = Math.floor(maxWidth/childWidth),
    parentWidth = nrOfChildren*(childWidth);

$('.parent').width(parentWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/te9fzaub/6/
Still waiting for a CSS method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to wrap 2 .child divs with additional div?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLf78vuo/)

```
<div class="bigParent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if 3 children fits in .parent's width and the 4th doesn't? I want the 4th to begin a new row but starting from the left but the .parent should have the width of 3 divs and must be aligned on center.

Comment: I will repeat, it doesn't need to be exactly as I exemplified, as: .bigParent .parent .child It can be 100 divs, it doesn't matter, the idea is so that the children are displayed on the center but they start from the left